# How to format xml using a stack?

Tags: python, xml, list, file, file-io

So I need this program to be able to read in a text file that looks like XML and have it check to see that the tags are properly nested.

**Question: How can I use a Stack to check that my sample XML file contains properly nested tags?**

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)



def xml_reader(filepath):
    ops = Stack()

    #Reads in file
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        alist = [list(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
    print(alist)

    for element in alist:
        if element == '<':
            ops.push(element)
    #Incomplete
```

Comment: I suspect that using a Stack is not your only problem. Your follow-up comments suggest that you aren't really familiar with parsing techniques, e.g. top-down recursive descent parsing, tokenisation, parser generators, etc etc. You can't expect to learn the whole of this branch of computer science by asking SO questions: find a good book on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to push every start element to the stack. When you get to the end element tag, you should pop the element from the stack. If element names don't match or if stack is not empty at the end of the process, your xml is not well structured.

python is not my language, but it should be something like this:

```
for element in alist:
    if element.startsWith( '<'):
        //elmName = element.strip<>
        ops.push(elmName )
    if element.startsWith('</'):
       //last = ops.pop
       //elmName = element.strip</>
       if(last != elmName)
          'Invalid xml'
 //for loop end
 if(ops.length > 0)
    'Invalid xml'
```

Comment: So how would I go about translating that into the code I have above?

Comment: since I'm reading this file character by character, I can't do something like ".startsWith" unfortunately.